# Multivariable Polynomial Regression

Tags: polynomials, regression

I want to regress my data into a function as: $a0+a_1K+a_2K^2+a_3T+a_4T^2+a_5KT$. But setting $\mathbf{a}=(\mathbf{K^\top K})^{-1} \mathbf{K^\top Y}$ does not work, I think the reason why is since the K and T elements of the matrix $\mathbf{K}$ are linearly dependent. Is there a way/ways to approximate the aforementioned function into my data?

Comment: Normally it is very unlikely to have linearly dependent observations. Could you describe how your $K$ looks like? Maybe you forgot to add a column in $K$ consisting of only ones as entries.

Comment: @MrYouMath Oh, sorry $Y$ represents my observations, the $K$ indices of my $\mathbf{K}$ matrix are values from 80 to 135 incremented by 5 for as we descend from each row whereas $T$ is from 1/12-1 incremented by 1/12 as we descend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, it looks like $T = \alpha K$,  i.e., you have a multicolinearity in your data. Hence, you don't need both $K$ and $T$ - you should get rid of one of them.

Comment: I believe I poorly stated the problem. I can’t think of a way to concisely explain why $K $ and $T$ are necessary, but I assure you they are. What I want is a method different from the one mentioned in my question that at least decently approximates my $Y$ values into the aforementioned function. Perhaps this can be done by using the variance of my parameters with respect to $Y$ or something similar to linear regression. I apologize for the vagueness, but I am grateful for your answer(s).

Comment: Generally, if indeed $T=\alpha K$, then no additional information is gained by including both $T$ and $K$, however still using the least squares approach you can use a pseudo inverse to fit the model in this case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Linear_least-squares

Answer (score 0):

If your $\boldsymbol{K}$ has the following structure it should work.

- Column 1: Only $1$ as entries.
- Column 2: $K$ as values
- Column 3: $K^2$ as values
- Column 4: $T$ as values
- Column 5: $T^2$ as values
- Column 6: $KT$ as values

Calculate the correlation matrix of your values. If you see very high correlations. You should remove one of the corresponding variables.